# Which ROS version to use with opencv

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I would like to use the feature detection library from opencv to detect an object and then navigate the mobile robot to the center of the object . I dont know only which version of ROS should install and to use it with opencv. I know that can use  CvBridge to Convert Between ROS Images and OpenCV Images.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237858/which-ros-version-to-use-with-opencv/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use any version of ROS you like starting from electric or any versions after it. http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-12-01**:
However if I am right, the OpenCV shipped with ROS Kinetic has some modules missing right ? For some of the latest OpenCV 3 features like tracking, you may have to make some changes in your CMakeLists.txt file and make it point towards a custom OpenCV+ OpenCV_contrib build.